# Consistent heuristic and A*

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, heuristics, searching

The following graph has consistent heuristic.
[image]

An A* algorithm will alter its first guess ACD to the correct shortest path ABD... if it has consistent heuristic, doesnt it mean, that AB should be found before AC?

Comment: Why do you think that?  Have you tried running A* by hand to see what it does?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft By definition consistent heuristic is, when h(n) <= c(n,n')+h(n').. In this case 5 <= 1+8, which is true, so its not overestimated.

Comment: I don't understand your question: A* doesn't guess paths. Look up the pseudocode for A* (e.g., in your textbook or on Wikipedia) and see for yourself what it _really_ does on that graph.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Because A* is greedy, and C's F value is lower than B's the algorithm will choose C first. So there will be a step 'in its runtime', when A* thinks the shortest path will go through C. Thats not true, and A* will also fix the path. 
My question is about, that I thought consistent heuristic means that the algorithm wont consider any misleading path's in its 'run'.

Answer (score 1):

A* isn't finished until all nodes with $f(n) < f(goal)$ are expanded.

So even though you have added $D$ to the open set you still need to expand $B$ because $f(B) = 11 < f(D) = 17$ after which $f(D)$ will become $12$

Comment: If I know it correctly, with consistent heuristic it should always choose the node which is on the shortest path. 
If I'm wrong, what's for the consistency?

Comment: But you will see each node as a neighbour of it's predecessor before it is picked. And only when the goal is *picked* is the algorithm done because that is when you know that any other path will have a higher cost.

Comment: If I have consistency, that also means the algorithm will never reopen its closed list. Does that mean that when D get updated C (its first parent)wont removed, and will stay there 'forever'?

Comment: No because when B is explored D is still in the open list and any node in the open list is allowed to change (though only when the new f is smaller than the old one). It's half the point of the open list.

Comment: Yes, I know, that D can change, but what about C? 
A* is greedy, therefore  we expolre C node before B, and when it has no more successors, we put it in the closed list. So, if we update D later, then C will be still in the closed list as 'garbage' (since its not on the shorest path but in the closed list) ?

Comment: Closed means don't explore this node any more, the best path to it is known. You frankly don't even need the explicit list for it. You can just add a boolean to each node isClosed.